# Encountering problems with flutter when building for archive

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, archive

I have been getting this frustrating error while building my flutter app for archive even after it runs well on simulator and builds sucessfully. I want to build for archive and send to the store but i keep getting this code signing error.

I have done lots of things like;

1. Toggling keychain login on and off.
2. Deleted derived data
3. Deintegrated pods and reinstalled
4. Regenerated machine certificates

And what is more frustrating is that it happens on this one project alone.

**Logs**

```
CodeSign /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ayrwpftzqolnkoekbffcnpggwwxu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/User/FlutterProjects/heala_doctor_app/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    
    Signing Identity:     "Appl"
    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.heala.doctor"
                          (f)
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign  --entitlements /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ayrwpftzqolnkoekbffcnpggwwxu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner.app.xcent --generate-entitlement-der /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ayrwpftzqolnkoekbffcnpggwwxu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app

/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ayrwpftzqolnkoekbffcnpggwwxu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app: the code cannot be read by the verifier (file system permissions etc.)
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Which XCode version are you using?

Comment: @tomerpacific am using 13.2.1